# Access Get subfolder of shared folder meetings

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I have the code below that should let me retrieve the meetings from a shared sub calendar, but it doesn't work.

If I only try to access the main shared calendar it works perfect, but not for the sub calendars..

could someone point me to the right way?

```
Public Sub getCalendarData(calendar_name As String, sDate As Date, eDate As Date, Optional recurItem As Boolean = True)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim oOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim oNS As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oAppointments As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim ItemsCal As Outlook.Items
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim fldCalendar As Outlook.Folder
    Dim iCalendar As Integer
    Dim nmsNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objDummy As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient

    'Set objects

    Set oOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set nmsNameSpace = oOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objDummy = oOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set objRecip = nmsNameSpace.CreateRecipient("shared calendar name")
    objRecip.Resolve

    'Set filter to grab items by date range
    strFilter = "[Start] >= " _
    & "'" & sDate & "'" _
    & " AND [End] <= " _
    & "'" & eDate & "'"

    With ItemsCal
        .Sort "[Start]"
        .IncludeRecurrences = recurItem
    End With

    If objRecip.Resolved Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set fldCalendar = nmsNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar).Folders("sub_calendar_name")

        If Not fldCalendar Is Nothing Then
            Set ItemsCal = fldCalendar.Items
            If Not ItemsCal Is Nothing Then
                For Each oAppointmentItem In ItemsCal.Restrict(strFilter)
                    Set objItem = oAppointmentItem
                    With oAppointmentItem
                        iCalendar = getSegmentIDByName(calendar_name)
                        meeting_id = insertAppointment(iCalendar, .Start, .End, scrubData(.Subject), scrubData(.Location), Format(.Start, "Long Time"), .duration, .Body)
                        Call GetAttendeeList(meeting_id, objItem, .Recipients)
                    End With
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Garbage cleanup
    Set oAppointmentItem = Nothing
    Set oAppoinments = Nothing
    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oOL = Nothing

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    'MsgBox "Error: " & Err & " | " & Error(Err)
    'Whenever error occurs, skip to next
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that `fldCalendar` is always returning `nothing` and I don't know what is wrong..

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that in the cached mode when you are accessing a default folder from another mailbox, you are not accessing the whole mailbox - the folder (but not its subfolders) is cached in your primary OST file.

You can add the whole mailbox as a delegate store (Advanced tab of the Exchange account properties dialog box) and then drill down to that folder from `Store.RootFolder` (where Store is retrieved from the `Namespace.Stores` collection).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), its version of [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetSharedDefaultFolder` (or `RDOSession.GetSharedMailbox`) returns a live folder ([RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm)), not its cached version, so you will be able to access the subfolders.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. So I should use something like Store.RootFolder.Folders(''calendar_name')? Or how can I retrieve the meetings inside that folder?

Comment: That is exactly right - Store.RootFolders.Folders("Calendar").Folders("Sub Folder name") or Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Sub Folder name")  would work.

Comment: `Dim rootFolder As Outlook.Stores
Set rootFolder = nmsNameSpace.Stores
Set fldCalendar = rootFolder.RootFolders.Folders("Calendar").Folders("Sub Folder name")`
But then, I will loose the connection with shared default folder..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "But then, I will loose the connection with shared default folder."?

Comment: I am using a shared calendar that has multiple sub folders. The app should go trough every sub folder and import all meetings from those sub folders, that's why I am using the GetSharedDefaultFolder option. And now, my problem is that sometimes that sub is working and sometimes not.. I marked your answer as ok because the first time I used the drill down to the specific folder worked but when I closed Outlook and then open it again it didn't worked..

Comment: Again, if you are using cached mode, the folder (without subfolders) will be in the OST file. Either use online (vs cached) mode or use Redemption (which does not cache the folder).

Comment: The shared calendar is set to download all folders in the Settings.. Should I uncheck that option?

Comment: That should help too.