# Shared inbox subfolder object not found error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The purpose of this code is to go through a shared folder in outlook and tell me the email subject and the received time and enter that into a spreadsheet. I made a version of this code that worked before on my own inbox, so I know that all of the excel parts work just fine. Once I knew that that worked I shifted it to the shared inbox (which is what I actually need) so I could tell where the errors are.

I've been fiddling with this for ages and from what I can tell this is getting hung up on the subfolders in this shared inbox. I've gone into the properties of the folder in outlook itself and it insists that these are the only folders, nonetheless, I've tried also having the name of the shared inbox and even the inbox itself as other combinations but none of that works. I have the reference libraries for outlook active, and like I said the code worked on my personal email.

The error that I'm getting is '-2147221233 (8004010f)' Attempted operation failed. An object could not be found. This is happening on line 17 (Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("MY TEAM'S FOLDER").Folders("THE FOLDER I WANT")) where the folder is set.

The structure that I want is 'my department's shared email'> that email's inbox > my team's folder > the subfolder I want   As far as I can see this should do that, but it won't. Seeing as this is the file path as far as I can tell, and the email is correct, and the code worked on my inbox before... I'm at a loss.

```vbs
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim olFolder As Folder
Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("SHARED EMAIL ADDRESS")
Set olFolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("MY TEAM'S FOLDER").Folders("THE FOLDER I WANT")

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In olFolder.Items


        Cells(i + 1, 1) = OutlookMail.Subject
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        
        i = i + 1

Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Get subfolder of shared folder meetings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199461/access-get-subfolder-of-shared-folder-meetings)

Answer (score 0):

The problematic line of code contains multiple property and method calls:

```
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("MY TEAM'S FOLDER").Folders("THE FOLDER I WANT")
```

I'd recommend breaking the chain of property and method calls by declaring each of them on a separate line of code. Thus, you will find the problematic call.

Anyway, to find whether such folder exists in a shared store I'd suggest iterating over all subfolders and getting their names, so you may find the required folder following that way.

```
For Each uFolder In olFolder.Folders
      If uFolder.Name = "MY TEAM'S FOLDER" Then
        MsgBox "MY TEAM'S FOLDER is found!"
      End If
Next uFolder
```

Comment: I tried splitting that down into: `Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("MY TEAM'S FOLDER") [there's a new line here idk why the comment isn't showing that]
Set ol.Folder = olFolder.Folders("THE FOLDER I WANT")`  but that's still picking up the my team's folder line as a problem. I tried the second code you set out and got that to run but it returns nothing, which I assume means it doesn't find anything, but it also doesn't return a result when I ask it to find "Inbox" so I'm not sure.